# Remove little checkbox from header checkbox when name is missing

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, checkbox

So I have a product grid, a non-mass-action one. Because I wanted to have like in the mass-action, those checkboxes as the first columns, the representative for all value data, I added the following in my grid:

```
 $this->addColumn('product_ids', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'field_name' => 'product_ids[]',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'values' => array('1', '2'),
 ));
```

Everything is cool, except that, because I didn't put any header name, my checkbox header looks like:

[image]

My question is how to remove that little checkbox, but not adding any name on the header? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$this->addColumn(
        'product_ids',
        array(
            'header' => ' ', //add this
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'field_name' => 'product_ids[]',
            'align' => 'center',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'values' => array('1', '2'),
    ));
```

Insert the header key and put a white space inside and this should work.